# Como funciona comparação de datas usando .toLocaleDateString();?

Tags: javascript

É uma dúvida que eu tenho a algum tempo e não consigo achar uma resposta em lugar algum da internet (procurei aqui e no SOen).

dado o seguinte código:

```
var hoje = new Date(2018, 08, 07).toLocaleDateString();
var dataQualquer = '08/05/2018';
if(dataQualquer < hoje) console.log('sucess!');
```

o `if`vai retornar `true` devido a data ser menor.
Se eu sibstituir a data por `'08/05/2019'`, ainda recebo `true`.
Resumindo: o `.toLocaleDateString`converte uma data em string. É possível comparar essa data com outra string de data, e ele funciona até certo ponto (desconsidera o ano, mas compara dia/mês).

A pergunta é: Como isso funciona afinal? Como o javascript compara duas strings e retorna true ou false dependendo do valor nelas? Sou ainda novo em programação comparado com a maioria nesse site, mas entendo que uma string preenchida deveria ser considerada um valor verdadeiro, e portanto deveria sempre retornar verdadeiro. E independente disso, por que compara os dias e meses, mas não os anos?

Sei que a pergunta é longa, mas realmente gostaria de saber o funcionamento desse processo.

Agradeço a atenção com antecedência.

Comment: `dataQualquer < hoje` dá `false` e não `true`

Comment: Funciona errado, pois não tem sentido nenhum comparar datas como string no formato proposto. A única solução real é esquecer tudo que tem no código da pergunta e começar certo do zero. Se vai usar strings, use a ordem AAAAMMDD e não faça nada de conversão. Se o formato já é data, compare como data ou numericamente (usando [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)). Se são 2 formatos diferentes, converta pra um formato só que faça sentido (ou string na ordem certa, ou inteiro/timestamp)

Comment: Eu entendo que funciona errado e sei a forma certa de fazer, a pergunta era como funcionava o sistema de comparação (>, <, >=, <=) entre strings. A questão das datas foi um exemplo no qual me deparei por acaso e usei como exemplo aqui. Mas agradeço a atenção e prestatividade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Strings` em Javascript são comparadas caractere por caractere, da esquerda pra direita até que os caracteres não sejam iguais, ou que não sobre mais nenhuma outra letra para comparar.

Você pode comparar frases:

```
"a" < "b" // true
"a" < "a" // false
"abc" < "aaa" // falso, porque b é maior que a
"abc" < "abd" // verdadeiro, porque c é menor que d
```

Assim como números, embora o resultado não seja o mesmo que comparar com os tipos numéricos.

```
"20" < "3" // verdadeiro, porque 2 é menor que 3
"50" > "100" // verdadeiro, porque 5 é maior que 1
"305" < "31" // verdadeiro, porque 1 é maior que 0
```

Isso acontece porque `strings` são comparadas [Lexicograficamente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), dando a cada caractere uma ordem que possa ser comparada.

> É possível comparar essa data com outra string de data, e ele funciona
>   até certo ponto (desconsidera o ano, mas compara dia/mês).

O mesmo acontece ao comparar duas datas no formato `string`:

```
"21/09/2018" < "21/10/2018" // true porque 0 é menor que 9 (mês)
"21/09/2018" < "31/10/2019" // verdadeiro, porque 3 é maior que 2 (dia)
"21/09/2020" < "31/10/2019" // ainda verdadeiro, porque 3 continua maior que 2 (desconsiderando assim o ano)
```

Por fim, para comparação entre datas, utilize sempre dois objetos do tipo `Date`, e note que para usar os operadores `!=` e `==` você precisa usar o método `date.getTime();`

```
var data1 = new Date();
var data2 = new Date(data1);

data1 == data2 // false, errado
data1 != data2 // false, errado
data1.getTime() == data2.getTime() // verdadeiro, correto
data1 > data2 // false, correto
data1 >= data2 // true, correto
data1 <= data2 // true, correto
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Eu sei como fazer de forma que funcione, queria entender apenas o por que do javascript agir desta forma, e como funcionava o 'raciocínio' da máquina nesta situação. O que eu faço geralmente é pegar a data de hoje com `new Date();` e comprar com a data atual da seguinte maneira: `var x = '08/05/2018'.split('/');` e então crio uma nova `new Date(x[2], x[1], x[0])` para poder comparar.

Comment: Correto:   sempre converta sua data para um objeto do tipo "Date" e compare direto o objeto "Date", nunca strings.

Answer (score 1):

> **A pergunta é**: Como isso funciona afinal? Como o javascript compara duas strings e retorna true ou false dependendo do valor nelas?

Ao comparar duas strings `"2" > "14"`, "2" será superior a "14", por causa (por ordem da esquerda para a direita) que 2 é superior a 1, e da mesma forma a sua dúvida  `"Se eu sibstituir a data por '08/05/2019', ainda recebo true"`, é devido conforme acima e abaixo explicado.

**Regra geral**

Para calcular comparações de string, o JavaScript ***converte cada caractere de uma string com seu valor ASCII***. Cada caractere, começando com o operador da esquerda, é comparado com o caractere correspondente no operador da direita.

No exemplo a seguir, veja que o caractere 7 é menor que 8, portanto, segundo a regra geral, independentemente do que vier após o caractere 7 do operador da esquerda e após o caractere 8 do operador da direita a expressão será sempre falso.

**Observe que no seu caso trata-se de comparação entre duas strings.**

```js
var hoje = new Date(2018, 08, 07).toLocaleDateString();
console.log(typeof hoje); //string

var dataQualquer = '08/05/2018';
console.log(typeof dataQualquer); //string

console.log(hoje);        // 07/09/2018
console.log(dataQualquer); //08/05/2018

if (dataQualquer<hoje){
  console.log("verdadeiro");
}else{
  console.log("falso");  //8 não é menor que 7
}
```

> Veja que o JavaScript não compara 7 com 8 e sim os seus valores ASCII

```
7 corresponde a 055 em ASCII
8 corresponde a 056 em ASCII
```

OBS: para valores numéricos, os resultados são iguais aos que você esperaria das suas aulas de álgebra da escola.

> facil né? Para caracteres numéricos os valores ASCII começam com 0 (048) e termina com 9 (057).

Então

```
           | cada centena representa o valor ASCII de cada caractere
07/09/2018 | 048 055 047 048 057 047 050 048 049 056
08/05/2018 | 048 056 047 048 053 047 050 048 049 056
                 ---
```

**Para caracteres alfabéticos não é tão fácil assim, veja o exemplo abaixo**

```js
    if ("mateus" < "Mateus"){
       console.log("verdadeiro");
    }else{
       console.log("falso");
    }
```

```
mateus | 109 097 116 101 117 115
Mateus | 077 097 116 101 117 115
         ---
```

> Os  valores ASCII para letras maiúsculas são menores que os correspondentes em letras minusculas.

**Uma das varias soluções, para seu caso, é usar a ordem ANO MES DIA**

```js
var hoje = new Date(2018, 08, 07).toLocaleDateString();
var dataQualquer = '08/05/2018';

 hoje = hoje.split("/").reverse().join("-"); //2018-09-07
 dataQualquer = dataQualquer.split("/").reverse().join("-"); // 2018-05-08
        

     if (dataQualquer<hoje){
       console.log("verdadeiro");
     }else{
       console.log("falso"); 
     }
```

```
 2018-09-07  | 050 048 049 056 045 048 057 045 048 055
 2018-05-08  | 050 048 049 056 045 048 053 045 048 056
                                       ---
```

Comment: Obrigado por me mostrar uma forma de fazer funcionar com strings, mesmo eu não tendo razão para fazer assim. Muito boa a resposta, gostaria de poder escolher duas respostas ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Opa @MáttheusSpoo, achei por bem fazer entender como o JavaScript realmente faz comparação. A melhor resposta mesmo foi do @ bacco que preferiu somente comentar.

Comment: Na verdade não, ele propos uma solução pro código apresentado, mas não respondeu o que eu perguntei. O que eu perguntei foi o que você respondeu, como o javascript compara as strings. Eu sei que o código na pergunta está errado e sei como resolver ele.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo entendi e fico feliz por ter ajudado.

Comment: Só pra complementar, a comparação de strings vai muito além do ASCII (pra ser mais preciso, os valores numéricos usados são os code points definidos pelo Unicode), conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052)

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente o javascript não possui um suporte nativo (mas [por que](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/20zx5n/why_doesnt_javascript_have_a_native_date/)?) para comparações entre datas, como @Vinícius mencionou: as strings são comparadas uma a uma e para você conseguir obter diferenças entre datas teria que utilizar o objeto Date() do javascript (que dá um trabalhão da pega).

Também existem algumas [técnicas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) montadas por desenvolvedores ao redor do mundo. Dê uma olhada caso interesse.

Particularmente eu recomendaria o [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/). Neste [link](https://blog.theodo.fr/2018/01/tips-tricks-date-handling-moment-js/) também há alguns exemplos explicando certinho como utilizar o moment.js corretamente e algumas características das datas em javascript.