# Quando eu comparo duas strings com os operadores "maior" e "menor" eu estou comparando o quê?

Tags: javascript, string

```js
var a = "a";
var b = "b";

if (a < b) // verdadeiro
  console.log(a + " é menor que " + b);

else if (a > b)
  console.log(a + " é maior que " + b);

else
  console.log(a + " e " + b + " são iguais.");
```

O exemplo acima retorna um valor booleano (`true` / `false`) quando é comparado com os operadores maior (`>`) e menor (`<`) os valores de `'a'` e `'b'`, que são strings.

Mas o que foi comparado para chegar a esse resultado de `true` ou `false`? É o tamanho da string, tamanho de bytes ou alguma outra coisa?

Comment: Vou editar a seu código,  vou trocar `print()` por `console.log()` pois está incomodando.

Comment: Sim! realmente é que eu tinha pegado esse código do site do MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings) esqueci de alterá-lo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> *Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using Unicode values.*

Ou seja, é feita a comparação lexicográfica, levando-se em conta os *Unicode code points* da string. Para entender melhor o que é um code point, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).

Mas de maneira bem resumida, cada caractere (e isso não se restringe a letras, mas também a dígitos, espaços, sinais de pontuação, emojis, etc) possui um valor numérico associado, chamado de code point. Quando duas strings são comparadas, os valores numéricos (os code points) correspondentes a cada caractere são levados em conta na comparação.

No caso, a letra `a` corresponde ao [code point U+0061](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm) (61 em hexadecimal, ou 97 em decimal), e a letra `b`, ao [code point U+0062](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0062/index.htm) (62 em hexa, 98 em decimal). Por isso a string `'a'` é considerada "menor" que a string `'b'`.

E isso não tem nada a ver com o tamanho da string:

```js
console.log('abacate' < 'bola'); // true
console.log('abacate' < 'abra'); // true
```

Segundo o [algoritmo descrito na especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) (item 3, se ambos os operandos forem strings), o que acontece é que o primeiro caractere de cada string (o valor de seus code points) é comparado. Se forem iguais, compara-se o segundo, e assim por diante, até encontrar algum que seja diferente.

No primeiro caso (`'abacate' < 'bola'`), os primeiros caracateres de cada string são `a` e `b` e como `a` é menor que `b` (o code point de `a` é menor que o code point de `b`), então a string `'abacate'` é "menor" que a string `'bola'`.

No segundo caso (`'abacate' < 'abra'`), o primeiro e segundo caractere das strings são iguais (ambas começam com `'ab'`), mas ao chegar no terceiro caractere, temos `a` e `r`, e como `a` é "menor" que `r` (pois o code point do `a` é U+0061 e do `r` é [U+0072](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/72/index.htm)), então a string `'abacate'` é menor que a string `'abra'`.

O tamanho das strings só é relevante em casos assim:

```js
console.log('aba' < 'abacate'); // true
```

---

Lembrando que isso não se restringe à letras, pois cada caractere existente possui um code point. Daí podemos ter coisas como:

```js
console.log('' > '丵124'); // true
```

Pois o emoji "" também possui um code point ([U+1F4A9](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm)), cujo valor é maior que o code point do caractere `丵` ([U+4E35](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4e35/index.htm)).

E vale lembrar de uma "armadilha" clássica, que é comparar strings que contêm dígitos:

```js
console.log('10000' > '2'); // false
```

Como estamos comparando strings, leva-se em conta o code point dos caracteres, e o caractere `1` possui o [code point U+0031](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/31/index.htm), enquanto o caractere `2` possui o [code point U+0032](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/32/index.htm), e portanto a string `'10000'` é considerada menor que a string `'2'`.

Se quer comparar os valores numéricos, deve-se transformar as strings em números, por exemplo usando [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
console.log(parseInt('10000') > parseInt('2')); // true, pois agora são números, e não strings
```

---

Vale lembrar que o Unicode também esconde suas próprias "armadilhas":

```js
console.log('á' < 'á'); // true
```

Isso acontece porque o primeiro `á` está em NFD, e o segundo, em NFC. Para entender melhor o que é isso, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052). Mas para resumir, o Unicode define duas formas diferentes de representar a letra `a` com acento agudo:

- forma composta (NFC), como um único code point: o próprio caractere `á`
- forma decomposta (NFD), como dois code points: o caractere `a` (sem acento) e o [próprio acento (code point U+0301)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)

Só que ambos, quando mostrados na tela, aparecem do mesmo jeito (`á`), e só "escovando os bits" das strings para ver quantos code points existem ali:

```js
// mostrar codepoints da string
function codepoints(s) { return Array.from(s).map(c => c.codePointAt(0).toString(16)).join(' '); }

// string em NFD, possui 2 code points
console.log(codepoints('á')); // 61 301
// string em NFC, possui 1 code point
console.log(codepoints('á')); // e1
```

Sendo assim, a primeira string acima na verdade tem dois code points, sendo que o primeiro é a letra `a`, que já vimos que é o code point U+0061, mas o primeiro code point da segunda string corresponde ao caractere `á`, cujo valor é [U+00E1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm), e por isso a primeira string é considerada "menor".

Isso pode ser resolvido normalizando ambas para a mesma forma (algo como `'á'.normalize('NFC')`, por exemplo), mas o que fazer exatamente vai depender de cada caso.

---

Existe ainda o método [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) para comparar strings de acordo com um *locale* específico (ou seja, de acordo com as regras de determinado idioma, pois isso varia bastante: os caracteres acentuados podem vir antes ou depois dos não-acentuados, há idiomas em que a ordem alfabética é diferente, etc). Mas acredito que já foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta (de qualquer forma, você pode ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445795/112052)).

Comment: Ótima! resposta eu entendi tudo o que você falou simples e direto no assunto muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Você está comparando os textos mesmo. Cada caractere é comparado um contra o outro em ordem que eles se encontram para determinar se são iguais, maiores ou menores.

Isso é uma laço usado internamente para comparar, então pode ser um pouco lento. Mas pode não ser nos casos que já dê para determinar diferença de alguma forma. Pode ser que apenas um caractere precise ser comparado. Se ele for diferente ou maior ou menor que o que está comparando na outra *string*, então já é possível obter um resultado, não precisa continuar. Se ele for igual então deve olhar o próximo caractere para determinar a relação entre eles, e assim vai até acabar os caracteres de uma ou outra *string*. Se elas foram iguais então terá verificar todo o texto e aí pode ficar um pouco lento, mas não tem outra forma.

Evidentemente que existem otimizações para indicar se o objeto é nulo ou se o tamanho é 0 ou mesmo se o tamanho for diferente. Pelo menos para testar a igualdade ou diferença se o tamanho for diferente já se sabe que é diferente. Não dá para saber se é maior ou igual se isso for necessário.

Na verdade, a comparação é um pouco mais complicada que isso em certos *collations*, mas a ideia geral é essa. E justamente o tal do *collate* é que determinará a regra exata de como comparar o texto.

Grosso modo é verificado se um caractere é igual, maior ou menor que o outro que está na mesma posição do outro texto de acordo com uma tabela estabelecida, em geral uma tabela alfabética. Pode ver mais sobre essas tabelas em [Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101).

Lembrando que os caracteres são representações gráficas mostradas nessas tabelas e o que está sendo comparado de verdade são números, então é uma comparação numérica fácil.

Note que em função do *collation* pode ter regras bem específicas entenda essa comparação de caractere um jeito para facilitar o entendimento. Se quiser saber os detalhes teria que pesquisar. É bem mais complicado e não interessa para a maioria das pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_de_compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o) da Mozila:

> Strings são comparadas baseadas na ordenação lexicografica padrão,
>   usando valores Unicode.

Então, palavras String são comparadas letra-a-letra. Você pode ver mais informações no site [javascript.info/comparison](https://javascript.info/comparison), que está em inglês.

Citação traduzida livremente:

> Para verificar se uma string é maior que outra, o JavaScript usa o chamado "dicionário" ou a ordem "lexicográfica".
>
> O algoritmo para comparar duas strings é simples:
>
> 1. Compare o primeiro caractere de ambas strings.
> 2. Se o primeiro caractere da primeira string for maior (ou menor) do que o da outra string, então a primeira string é maior (ou menor) do
>      que a segunda.
> 3. Caso contrário, se ambos primeiros caracteres forem o mesmo, compare o segundo caractere da mesma maneira.
> 4. Repita até chegar no fim de cada string.
> 5. Se ambas strings possuírem o mesmo tamanho, elas são iguais.
> 6. Caso contrário, a string com mais caracteres é maior.