# Como mostrar uma lista sempre ordenada à medida em que novos elementos são inseridos

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando implementar uma lista, na qual, cada número digitado seja inserido e contado em sequência, tal qual no exemplo abaixo:

```
lista = ['0']
while True:
    ean = input('digite aqui: ' )
    lista.append(ean)
    print map(lista)
```

Gostaria que o retorno fosse...

```
digite aqui: 2                                                                                                                               
['1', '2']                                                                                                                            

digite aqui: 3                                                                                                                              
['1', '2', '3']                                                                                                                       

digite aqui: 4                                                                                                                               
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Gostaria que, independentemente do que fosse inserido no `"input"`, o programa listasse os elementos em ordem crescente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a lista deve guardar strings mas você quer ordenar pelos valores numéricos, é interessante inserir os valores somente se forem números. Para isso você pode usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter a string em número, e capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) caso não seja (pois se não for número, não fará sentido tentar ordenar pelo valor numérico).

```
lista = ['0']
while True:
    n = input('digite aqui: ')
    try:
        int(n) # tenta converter para número
        lista.append(n)
        print(sorted(lista, key=int)) # ordena a lista pelo valor numérico
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')
```

Fiz assim porque parece que quer que a lista tenha strings (já que na saída os números estão entre aspas).

Mas por que eu fiz tudo isso se a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460547/112052) parece ter funcionado? Bom, provavelmente você só deve ter testado com números de um dígito. Pois ordenar strings desta forma esconde algumas armadilhas. Ex:

```
lista = ['1', '2', '10']
lista.sort()
print(lista) # ['1', '10', '2']
```

Repare que o `10` veio antes do `2`. Isso porque strings são compostas de caracteres, e mesmo dígitos são considerados caracteres, e a ordenação leva em conta a ordem lexicográfica dos mesmos, e não os seus valores numéricos ([nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052) tem uma explicação mais detalhada - apesar dela ser em JavaScript, os conceitos são basicamente os mesmos e te ajudará a entender porque o `10` veio antes do `2` na ordenação).

Se você testar apenas com números de um dígito, o problema não aparece. Mas é um detalhe importante a se atentar.

Já ao fazer `key=int`, eu converto as strings para o seu respectivo valor numérico, e este é considerado na ordenação. Ou seja:

```
lista = ['1', '2', '10']
lista.sort(key=int)
print(lista) # ['1', '2', '10']
```

Outra diferença é que no primeiro exemplo usei [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), que não modifica a lista original. Já [`lista.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) modifica a própria lista (ou seja, dependendo do que você precisa, usar um ou outro faz diferença).

---

Se bem que não me parece muito eficiente ordenar a lista toda hora. Se precisa sempre mostrá-la de forma ordenada, uma alternativa é garantir que os elementos sempre estejam em ordem.

Para isso podemos usar o módulo [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), que possui métodos - como o [`insort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) - para inserir de forma ordenada na lista:

```
from bisect import insort

lista = [0]
while True:
    try:
        insort(lista, int(input('digite aqui: ')))
        print(lista)
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')
```

Assim, os elementos sempre estarão em ordem, bastando imprimir a lista diretamente.

Outra diferença é que agora a lista contém números em vez de strings (ou seja, eles são impressos sem as aspas). Se quer muito que sejam impressos como strings, você pode convertê-los na hora de imprimir, fazendo `print(list(map(str, lista)))` em vez de só `print(lista)`.

Answer (score 1):

Observe que nesta questão você terá que implementar um `laço de repetição`.

Independentemente do laço que você utilizar, precisarás de uma `"flag"` de parada. Esta flag irá interromper a digitação dos possíveis valore subsequentes. Pois, você não pode simplesmente, inserir `indefinidamente` valores na lista. Além disso, em cada iteração a lista deve ser exibida da melhor forma possível, ou seja, de forma `"ordenada"`.

Diante destas questões, desenvolvi o seguinte código...

```
# Este programa solicita uma flag para ser executado ou encerrado. Se a
# flag for "N" ou "n", o programa será encerrado. Se a flag for "S" ou "s",
# o programa solicitará um número, depois insere o número de forma ordenada
# na lista, depois exibe a lista atualizada e ordenada, em seguida, reinicia
# o loop que, de acordo com a decisão do usuário, poderá continuar o processo ou
# encerra-lo.

from bisect import insort
from time import sleep

cont = 0
lista = list()
continuar = True
while continuar == True:

    cont += 1
    if cont == 1:
        palavra = 'algum'
    else:
        palavra = 'outro'

    # Solicita uma flag para continuar a execução ou encerra-lo.
    resposta = str(input(f'Desejas inserir {palavra} número? [S/N] ')).strip()
    while resposta not in 'SsNn':
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resposta = str(input(f'Desejas inserir {palavra} número? [S/N] ')).strip()

    # Caso a flag inserida seja "S" ou "s", inicia-se a inserção de valores na lista.
    if (resposta == 'S') or (resposta == 's'):
        # Captura e trata o valor digitado:
        while True:
            try:
                v = int(input(f'Digite o {cont}º número: '))
                break
            except:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

        # Inseri o valor inteiro de forma ordenada na lista.
        insort(lista, v)

        # Exibi a lista atualizada e ordenada a cada interação do loop.
        print(f'\033[32mLista atualizada e ordenada: {lista}\033[m')

        # Reinicia o Loop.
        continuar = True

    # Caso a flag inserida seja "N" ou "n", encerra-se a execução do programa.
    else:
        print('\033[31mEncerrando o programa!')
        # Animação da barra de progresso de encerramento.
        for c in range(1, 48):
            print(chr(46), end='')
            sleep(0.1)
        print()

        continuar = False
        break
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/fvtccltp-solkarped)