# Como remover de uma lista valores que estão em outra?

Tags: python, lista

Tenho 2 dicionários, um com os horários disponíveis, e outro com os horários agendados:

```
schedules_dict = {1: ['00:00'], 2: ['00:30', '00:45'], 3: ['00:00', '00:30', '00:45']}
appointments_dict = {1: ['00:00'], 2: ['00:30'], 3: ['00:00', '00:30']}
```

E preciso mostrar apenas os horários que ainda estão disponíveis:

```
output = {2: ['00:45'], 3: ['00:45']}
```

Tentativa:

```
for key in schedules_dict.keys():
    if key in appointments_dict.keys():            
        print(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é transformar as listas de horários em [`set`'s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) e subtraí-los. Assim, o que sobrar são os horários disponíveis:

```
schedules_dict = {1: ['00:00'], 2: ['00:30', '00:45'], 3: ['00:00', '00:30', '00:45']}
appointments_dict = {1: ['00:00'], 2: ['00:30'], 3: ['00:00', '00:30']}

output = {}
for indice, disponiveis in schedules_dict.items():
    if indice in appointments_dict:
        # vê os horários que sobraram
        sobrou = list(set(disponiveis) - set(appointments_dict[indice]))
        if len(sobrou) > 0:
            output[indice] = sobrou
    else:
        output[indice] = disponiveis

print(output) # {2: ['00:45'], 3: ['00:45']}
```

Um detalhe é que `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos. Se quiser que os horários estejam em ordem, basta trocar para usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sobrou = sorted(set(disponiveis) - set(appointments_dict[indice]))
```

A princípio, comparar strings contendo dígitos [nem sempre funciona da forma esperada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440503/112052), mas neste caso os horários estão no formato HH:MM (sempre com 2 dígitos, de acordo com a [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)), então a ordenação é feita corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

veja se isso te ajuda:

```
schedules_dict = {1: ['00:00'], 2: ['00:30', '00:45'], 3: ['00:00', '00:30', '00:45']}
appointments_dict = {1: ['00:00'], 2: ['00:30'], 3: ['00:00', '00:30']}
for key in schedules_dict:
    for i in schedules_dict[key]:
        if i not in appointments_dict[key]:
            print(key,i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Apenas fortalecendo o entendimento.

Pode consultar o utilitário de ajuda do Python, caso precise de mais orientações sobre essa função

apenas entre no shell interativo e digite:

```
help(set())
```

help ("algo que precise saber")

Assim tera mais ajuda.

[Mais informação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/.)