# Por que os números acima de 100 não são utilizados na contagem?

Tags: javascript

Tenho este exercício:

- Passar uma lista com pontuação de jogos de basquete
- Dessa lista, toda vez que uma pontuação fosse maior que a pontuação anterior, iria adicionar um ponto
- Além da pontuação de quantas vezes o jogador superou a própria pontuação, no final também mostrará em qual jogo ele fez a menor pontuação

O código que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

```js
let stringPontuacoes = "30 40 20 4 51 25 42 38 56 0"
let teste1 = '10 20 20 30 20 50 0'
let teste2 = '20 30 10 50 90 10 100 150 20 10 30 56 0'
let teste3 = '10 20'

let desempenho = (string) => {
    let melhorDesempenho = 0;
    let piorJogo = 0;
    let arrayConverter = string.split(' ');
    let firstScore = arrayConverter[0];
    let subsequente = firstScore;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayConverter.length; i++) {
        if (arrayConverter[i] > subsequente) {
            subsequente = arrayConverter[i];
            melhorDesempenho++;
        }
    }
    let convertNumber = arrayConverter.map(Number);
    let min = Math.min(...convertNumber)
    piorJogo = convertNumber.indexOf(min) + 1;
    console.log([melhorDesempenho, piorJogo]);
} 

desempenho(stringPontuacoes); //resultado = [3, 10]
desempenho(teste1); //resultado = [3, 7]
desempenho(teste2); //resultado = [3, 13]; era pra ser [5, 13]
desempenho(teste3);//resultado [1, 1]
```

O problema está sendo com as listas que possuem números maiores que 99. Alguém saberia me dizer por que isso acontece? No caso, ele não conta nenhuma pontuação acima do 99, não adicionando um ponto na lista para esses números. O código faz sentido na minha cabeça, o único problema está sendo com esses números a partir de 100. As listas que não os possuem dão o resultado correto.

Comment: `let teste2 = '20 30 10 50 90 10 100 150 20 10 30 56 0'` para essa string, o resultado não deveria ser `[7, 13]`  e não `[5, 13]`?

Comment: Não, pois ele só soma um ponto se o próximo número for maior que a maior pontuação anterior. Então começaria com 30 > 20 [1], 50 > 30 [2], 90 > 50 [3], 100 > 90 [4] e 150 > 100 [5].

Comment: de qualquer forma, para saber se o **número** é maior, não deveria converter para numero? assim por exemplo `if (Number(arrayConverter[i]) > Number(subsequente))`  veja aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/svd05rak/

Comment: Nossa, agora foi. Pelo visto esse era o problema. No caso ele não estava pegando os números maiores que 99 porque estava comparando entre strings? Eu achei que fosse funcionar porque com os números menores que 100 estava funcionando normalmente. Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Funcionou por coincidência, já que `'10' > '90'` é `false`, apesar de estar comparando strings (textos) em vez de números. O problema é que `'100' > '90'` também dá `false`, pelo mesmo motivo. Entenda melhor lendo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Agora ficou bem claro.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema é que você esta fazendo comparações entre valores do tipo string e não number.

Seguindo a forma que você desenvolveu, depois que você converteu a string para array com este código `let arrayConverter = string.split(' ');`,  você pode converter todos os valores para number desta maneira `const arrayConvertedNumber = arrayConverter.map(value => Number(value));`.

Seguindo a sua lógica eu fiz esse exercício de uma forma mais simplificada que pode te ajudar nos estudos.

```
const scores1 = [30, 40, 20, 4, 51, 25, 42, 38, 56, 0];
const scores2 = [10, 20, 20, 30, 20, 50, 0];
const scores3 = [20, 30, 10, 50, 90, 10, 100, 150, 20, 10, 30, 56, 0];
const scores4 = [10, 20];

function desempenhoDoJogador(scores) {
  const lowerValueFromScore = Math.min(...scores);
  const lowestScoreGame = scores.indexOf(lowerValueFromScore) + 1;
  let counterBestScore = 0;
  let nextScore = scores[0];

  for (let score of scores) {
    if (score > nextScore) {
      nextScore = score;
      counterBestScore++;
    }
  }

  const Message = `O jogador superou a sua pontuação ${counterBestScore} vezes, e a menor pontuação foi no jogo ${lowestScoreGame}`;

  console.log(Message);
}

desempenhoDoJogador(scores1); //3, 10
desempenhoDoJogador(scores2); //3, 7
desempenhoDoJogador(scores3); //5, 13 
desempenhoDoJogador(scores4); //1, 1
```

[Clique aqui para visualizar o código no stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/desempenho-do-jogador?file=index.js) 
[Documentação do For of](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)