# Função sorted fazendo referência a chaves de um dicionário para definir o critério de ordenação

Tags: python, dicionário

```
dict = {'dc':20,'ba':10,'aa':5,'db':30,'za':1}

dict_2 = sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda dict: dict[1], reverse = True)

print(dict_2)
```

Quando eu coloco dict[1] no argumento da função tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
[('db', 30), ('dc', 20), ('ba', 10), ('aa', 5), ('za', 1)]
```

Quando eu coloco dict[0] no argumento da função tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
[('za', 1), ('dc', 20), ('db', 30), ('ba', 10), ('aa', 5)]
```

Pelo que eu entendi, se eu colocar `dict[1]` ele começa a ordenar considerando a segunda letra da string da chave e quando coloco `dict[0]` ele começa a ordenar considerando a primeira letra da string da chave. Minha dúvida é a seguinte: quando eu faço uma referência `dict['x']` não deveria ser retornado o valor para a chave 'x'? Para eu conseguir ordenar pela posição na string eu não deveria ter que colocar `dict['x'[0]]` ou `dict['x'[1]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *se eu colocar `dict[1]` ele começa a ordenar considerando a segunda letra da string da chave*

Não é nada disso.

---

Primeiro, vamos ver [o que `items()` retorna](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for item in dict.items():
    print(item, type(item))
```

Saída:

```
('dc', 20) <class 'tuple'>
('ba', 10) <class 'tuple'>
('aa', 5) <class 'tuple'>
('db', 30) <class 'tuple'>
('za', 1) <class 'tuple'>
```

`items()` retorna várias [**tuplas**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), sendo que cada tupla contém uma chave do dicionário e seu respectivo valor.

Ou seja, `sorted` irá ordenar estas tuplas. E o critério de ordenação foi indicado pelo `lambda`. Então quando eu faço:

```
lambda dict: dict[1]
```

Estou dizendo que esta é uma função que recebe um parâmetro (no caso, chamado `dict`) e retorna o elemento que está na posição 1.

Mas como estou passando várias tuplas para `sorted`, então o `lambda` receberá uma tupla como argumento, e pegará o elemento da tupla que está na posição 1. No caso, será o valor (que no seu dicionário, é o `20`, `30`, etc). Pode ver:

```
for item in dict.items():
    print(f'posição zero: {item[0]}, posição 1: {item[1]}')
```

Saída:

```
posição zero: dc, posição 1: 20
posição zero: ba, posição 1: 10
posição zero: aa, posição 1: 5
posição zero: db, posição 1: 30
posição zero: za, posição 1: 1
```

Ou seja, quando você usa `dict[1]` no `lambda`, está dizendo para ordenar pelos valores (`20`, `30`, etc), e quando você usa `dict[0]`, está dizendo para ordenar pelas chaves (`aa`, `ba`, etc). E claro, como você usou `reversed=True`, o resultado estará em ordem descrescente. E vale lembrar que números são comparados de acordo com o seu valor numérico, e strings, de acordo com a ordem alfabética (para ser mais preciso, é pela ordem [lexicográfica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440503/112052)).

---

Dito isso, eu mudaria o nome do parâmetro do `lambda`, pois `dict`, além de ser [uma das funções *builtin*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict), ainda passa a impressão errada de que ali tem um dicionário. Não tem, pois como já vimos, ali naquele ponto temos uma tupla contendo uma chave e seu respectivo valor, então mude para algo como `item`, por exemplo.

De qualquer forma, se quer ordenar pela primeira letra de cada chave, teria que ser algo assim:

```
dict_2 = sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda item: item[0][0], reverse = True)
```

Lembre-se: `item` é uma tupla contendo uma chave e um valor. Na posição zero `item[0]` temos a chave, que no seu caso são strings. Então para pegar o primeiro caractere desta string basta fazer `item[0][0]`.

Se quisesse ordenar pelo segundo caractere, bastaria mudar para:

```
dict_2 = sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda item: item[0][1], reverse = True)
#                                                        ↑
#                                    aqui (1 indica o segundo caractere da string)
```

Comment: você é sensacional! Muito obrigado pela explicação detalhada e por dedicar esse tempo a escrevê-la. Estou iniciando os estudos em programação e saber que essa comunidade é tão bacana e se ajuda me motiva bastante a continuar aprendendo