# Ao tentar comparar valores maiores e menores ele me retorna um número diferente:

Tags: javascript

```js
let stringPontuacoes = "30, 40, 20, 4, 51, 25, 42, 38, 56, 30, 45, 9"


function avaliaPontuacoes(stringPontuacoes) {
  let pontuacoes = stringPontuacoes.split(", ")
  let qtdQuebraDeRecords = 0
  let piorJogo = 1
  let maiorPontuacao = pontuacoes[0]
  let menorPontuacao = pontuacoes[0]

  for (let i = 1; i < pontuacoes.length; i++) {
    if (pontuacoes[i] > maiorPontuacao) {
      maiorPontuacao = pontuacoes[i]
      qtdQuebraDeRecords++
    } else if (pontuacoes[i] < menorPontuacao) {
      menorPontuacao = pontuacoes[i]
      piorJogo = i + 1;
    }
  }
  return [qtdQuebraDeRecords, piorJogo]
}

console.log(avaliaPontuacoes(stringPontuacoes))
```

Por algum motivo quando o maior número é comparado com o 9, ele retorna como se o 9 fosse maior. Por quê?

Comment: Aqui `if (pontuacoes[i] > maiorPontuacao)` você está fazendo a comparação entre os valores UNICODE dos caracteres das strings. Depois que explodir a string em um array de strings de numerais, `let pontuacoes = stringPontuacoes.split(", ")`, deve ainda converter os elementos do array para numérico para aí então os processar.

Comment: Complementando o que já foi explicado acima: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que vc está comparando strings e não números.
Para corrigir o problema nos seus IFs use o parseInt()

```
if (parseInt(pontuacoes[i]) > parseInt(maiorPontuacao))
...
else if (parseInt(pontuacoes[i]) < parseInt(menorPontuacao))
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema

Alternativamente se for possível vc pode fazer seu array com números

```
let stringPontuacoes = [30, 40, 20, 4, 51, 25, 42, 38, 56, 30, 45, 9]
```