# Elemento no meio do vetor após fazer ordenação com a função sort()

Tags: javascript

Estou aprendendo linguagem JavaScript e estou fazendo alguns testes para praticar o uso de vetores. Porém a saída dos valores do vetor fica fora de ordem quando a variável index (dentro do laço for) assume um valor maior ou igual a 10.

```
let num  = []

/**
 * Acrescenta elementos ao fim do vetor / array
 */
function empilhar(item){
    
    num.push(item % 2 == 0 ? item / 2 : item + 1)
    num.sort()

    console.log(num + ' <|--')

}

for(let index = 0; index < 11; index++){
    console.log(`Índice do elemento ${index}: ${num.indexOf(index) != -1 ? num.indexOf(index) : `não encontrado`}`)
    empilhar(index)

}

console.log(num)
```

No exemplo que utilizei a saída fica:

```
Índice do elemento 0: não encontrado
0 <|--
Índice do elemento 1: não encontrado
0,2 <|--
Índice do elemento 2: 1
0,1,2 <|--
Índice do elemento 3: não encontrado
0,1,2,4 <|--
Índice do elemento 4: 3
0,1,2,2,4 <|--
Índice do elemento 5: não encontrado
0,1,2,2,4,6 <|--
Índice do elemento 6: 5
0,1,2,2,3,4,6 <|--
Índice do elemento 7: não encontrado
0,1,2,2,3,4,6,8 <|--
Índice do elemento 8: 7
0,1,2,2,3,4,4,6,8 <|--
Índice do elemento 9: não encontrado
0,1,10,2,2,3,4,4,6,8 <|--
Índice do elemento 10: 2
0,1,10,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,8 <|--
[
  0, 1, 10, 2, 2,
  3, 4,  4, 5, 6,
  8
]
```

Isso é uma característica da linguagem / algum bug ou sou eu que estou cometendo algum erro de lógica? Pois quando o index assume valores menores que 9 a ordenação funciona normalmente.

Comment: O link indicado acima no box azul tem a explicação, e também mostra como resolver. Respondendo a pergunta: sim, é uma característica da linguagem converter tudo pra string antes de ordenar, o que muitos consideram uma falha grave de design

Comment: Segue [link da documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), que explica que os elementos são primeiro convertidos pra string. E pra entender melhor porque a comparação tem esse resultado, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052)